Typescript path aliases not working in docker
I am trying to run my app in docker.
this is my tsconfg.json file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["api/models/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["api/middlewares/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["api/controllers/*"],
      "@jobs/*": ["api/jobs/*"],
      "@services/*": ["api/services/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["api/utils/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["api/routes/*"],
      "@validations/*": ["api/validations/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@helpers/*": ["api/helpers/*"],
      "@root/*": ["../*"]
    },
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "lib": ["es2017"],
  "ts-node": {
    // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}

when i run npx tsc-alias in docker container it does not update paths in dist folder. But runs fine without docker.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
